# Wrapping and unwrapping HTML content in tDOM

Tags: dom, tcl, tdom

Would you please tell me if these are correct methods of wrapping selections in a new tag and unwrapping the contents of a tag "into" the parent at the same node location? They appear to work in my HTML content but would like to know if this is the correct approach.

Also, when a child node is replaced, is the replaced child node released from memory or should that be coded?

Thank you.

```
proc wrap {path tag} {
  foreach item [$::doc selectNodes $path] {
    set wrapper [$::doc createElement $tag]
    # This fails if $item has more than one child node.
    # $wrapper appendFromList [[$item childNodes] asList]
    foreach child [$item childNodes] {
      $wrapper appendChild $child
    }
    [$item parentNode] replaceChild $wrapper $item
  }
}

proc unwrap {path} {
  foreach item [$::doc selectNodes $path] {
    foreach child [$item childNodes] {
      [$item parentNode] insertBefore $child $item
    }
    $item delete
  }
}
```

Comment: I *think* tDOM does garbage collection, provided you don't hold onto references.

Comment: tDOM requires you to explicitly `delete` a node (like you do in your `unwrap` proc); `replaceChild`, `removeChild` will maintain at least one reference in what tDOM calls a document-fragment list, internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `unwrap` implementation looks good to me, but does `replaceChild` really give you a wrapper element?

I'd expect `wrap` to work like:

```
proc wrap {path tag} {
  set els [$::doc selectNodes $path]
  if {[llength $els]} {
    set el [lindex $els 0]
    set wrapper [$::doc createElement $tag]
    [$el parentNode] insertBefore $wrapper $el
    foreach el $els {
      $wrapper appendChild $el
    }
  }
}
```

---

Some more remarks:

- Maybe pass around the document explicitly, rather than refer to a globally scoped variable `::doc` all over the place?
- Maybe return the wrapper element as a return value of `wrap`, or the empty string to signal a no-match?

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I forgot that `::doc` is not the the text document but only a reference and thought it would pass a large value around. Regarding `replaceChild` giving a wrapper element, I'm not following. Do you mean will `replaceChild` replace the old node with a new node, including the new nodes children? Unless I made a mistake, it appears to in my test cases, much like building a document fragment in JavaScript and adding the fragment's content to the DOM once.

Comment: Regarding your comment below the question, does that mean that in your code sample here, `$els` should be deleted explicitly once all its child nodes have been moved into the wrapper? That seems right since it is at that point an empty container but still in the DOM. And, if `replaceChild` does still accomplish this task, the replaced node still needs to be explicitly deleted, such that in my earlier code sample, `$item` has to be deleted. Thank you.

Comment: Ad "I'm not following": Using your original `wrap` implementation, a call like `wrap {//p} "div"` on `<p>Hello</p><p>cruel</p><p>World</p>` returns `<div>Hello</div><div>cruel</div><div>World</div>`, rather than `<div><p>Hello</p><p>cruel</p><p>World</p></div>`. I do not see any wrapping in there.

Comment: Ad "explicit deletes": In your wrap implementation, there is no need for deletes at all. You create a new node (wrapper) at a specific position in the document tree, and move existing ones into that wrapper. Why would you delete anything here? Think of `appendChild` as a move-operation, in fact.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I wasn't trying to wrap the selected nodes in a new tag but wrap the children of those parent nodes into a new parent tag. I see now how what I wrote was confusing. I wanted exactly what you wrote in your comment; that is replace the parent `p` tag with a `div` tag. My description was confusing. My apologies.

Comment: In the wrap procedure I was referring to whether or not the original parent node `$item`  would need deleted when using `replaceChild`. All of its child nodes were moved into the new parent tag `$wrapper` and then `replaceChild` used to replace the empty parent `$item` with the newly created `$wrapper`. I understood your comment under the original question to mean that `$item` must be explicitly deleted. But my description was confusing. In your recent example using the `p` and `div` tags, I would be asking do the old `p` tags need to be deleted or will `replaceChild` take care of that?